# why only clone and finalize are protected method in object calss?

Tags: java, object, equals, hashcode, protected

I  understand the purpose of making the clone and finalize method as protected, I wanted to understand why hashcode() and equals method are not declared as protected

Comment: Simply put, because you would like to use these outside of the class

Answer (score 6):

Because you want to call `hashcode` and `equals` methods from the outside of that given class.

`protected` allows access only from the same package and extending classes.

Comment: Hi @antoniossss, thanks for response, but Object class is root package for all the classes, so I believe it should be available to all the classes. one more reason why clone and finalize methods are protected is to make overriding it with either protected or public visibility. so why not hashcode and equals

Comment: You are wrong. `protected` methods of class `a.b.Class` are visible in package `a.b` but not in `a.b.z`

Answer (score 1):

You "understand the purpose of making the clone and finalize method as protected". But what is the purpose actually?

Calling `Object.clone` will throw an exception if the method isn't overridden and if `Cloneable` isn't implemented. Thus this method isn't ready to use.

`Object.finalize` is according to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) "called by the garbage collector". Thus it is for internal usage only.

In contrast to these both methods are `Object.equals` and `Object.hashCode` ready to use and not for internal usage.

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) of `Object.hashCode` says:

> This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those
>   provided by `HashMap`.

Thus it is intended to be used by other objects. If `hashCode` wouldn't be declared `public` this functionality would be limited usable.

`Object.equals` is a [symmetric](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method. If `Object.equals` wouldn't be declared `public`, suppose we have a local variable `b` of a type from another package and whose `equals` method isn't visible to `this`. We want to ckeck if `b` and `this` are equal. We couldn't call `b != null && b.equals(this)` but we could still call `this.equals(b)`. Does it makes sense to limit a symmetric method to be callable by one of both objects only?
See also `Comparable`.